# Workers in django run on heroku are hanging on post when client has flaky connection

Tags: python, django, post, heroku, gunicorn

We are running django/gunicorn server on heroku. Most of our users are in a country where the mobile network is not-that-great, so frequently they have flaky connections.

Most of our requests are "raw posts" from mobile devices and it seems that even when the POST request is not fully transmitted the request is already being sent off to be handled by a gunicorn worker. When the worker tries to process the request and read the data it simply hangs waiting for the remaining data. While this behaviour makes sense for reading file/image data in "streaming" mode, it makes no sense in our case because all our posts are relatively small and could be easily read by the web server as a whole and only then forwarded to our gunicorn worker.

This early handoff causes trouble when we have many such requests in parallel - because all the workers might get blocked. Currently we solve the problem by increasing number of workers/dynos but it is pretty costly. I could not find any way to force either the web server or gunicorn to wait and only forward the request to a worker once it is fully transmitted.

Is there a way to make heroku's web server/gunicorn only transfer the request to a gunicorn worker when it has been fully transmitted from the client side (fully received by the server)?

Some example code (we've added newrelic 'per-instruction' tracing to make sure that this is the exact line that causes the problem):

```
def syncGameState(request):
    transaction = agent.current_transaction()
    with agent.FunctionTrace(transaction, "syncGameState_raw_post_data", 'Python/EndPoint'):
        data = request.raw_post_data
    with agent.FunctionTrace(transaction, "syncGameState_gameStateSyncRequest", 'Python/EndPoint'):
        sync_request = sync_pb2.gameStateSyncRequest()
    with agent.FunctionTrace(transaction, "syncGameState_ParseFromString", 'Python/EndPoint'):
        sync_request.ParseFromString(data)
```

Here are the New Relic measurements for this example slow request (it was a POST with 7K of data). Reading the POST takes 99% of the method time....

[image]

Comment: I think that heroku timeout is 10 seconds. I'm not test it, but perhaps you can change [gunicorn timeout](http://gunicorn.org/configure.html#timeout) in [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#procfile): `web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi -t 3 -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT`

Comment: It's 30 seconds by default. We already set timeout in gunicorn ... but the thing is that in this case I would cancel requests which otherwise (even if after 20 seconds) would succeed, I don't really want to do it. What I want to do is not to block my workers while the requests is   transmitted over the network.

Comment: I'm confused with your post. When you talk about workers, you talk about 'web dynos' or about 'worker dynos'? 'Worker dynos' should not be locked while data is transfered because is 'web dyno' who collect data. It is not? (Also, please, Would you be so kind as to tell me what is that slow country? )

Comment: I am talking about gunicorn workers. There are several dynos and on each dyno single gunicorn is running but it usually spawns several workers with -w <workers> option: [gunicorn configuration](http://gunicorn.org/configure.html). In my case i have it set to -w 12 now. Those are separate processes (children of gunicorn). Every request that is routed to particular dyno is routed through gunicorn to one of it's workers. And it seems that the worker after receiving the request to handle is "held" on reading the data (while reading raw_post_data property).

Comment: Perhaps you can set an alarm before raw post data assignment and disable it at end of assignment. http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#example . Timeout signal is a simple SIGTERM signal.

Comment: No, that would not work. The request is already killed after 30 seconds by gunicorn (i have timeout set to 30s - same as heroku timeout). The thing is that I do not want the hang at all - I would rather have gunicorn or - better - the web server (nginx apparently) on heroku to hold the request, as they are much better suited for that - in my case the whole python process with xx MB of RAM is held idle for 30 seconds. If this request is held until ready in gunicorn or in nginx, that would be much more efficient...

Comment: Hi @JarekPotiuk, have you fixed your issue?

Comment: No - it's not fixed yet. It's still workarounded as described above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the real issue here is that gunicorn is blocking. This is because gunicorn (by default) uses synchronous workers to run your tasks. This means that when a web request hits gunicorn it will block until it has returned a response--in your case, a long time.

To get around this issue, you can use gevent with gunicorn to do non-blocking IO. Since most of your time is spent doing IO stuff, this will ensure gunicorn can handle many more web requests in parallel.

To use gevent with gunicorn you need to install gevent (`pip install -U gevent`), and change your gunicorn startup command by adding: `gunicorn -k gevent` (this will tell gunicorn to use gevent as the worker).

Comment: I it's the right direction indeed (but not exactly), but going that route would make the app more complex. I would have to separate request reading process (so getting post data from request) from request processing. This would enable to run many more parallel reading threads (don't require too much memory) and some smaller number of processing processes. The default setup that you proposed will not provide that really, because at the time when I have same process doing reading from post and processing it - I have the same problem (I cannot increase the number of processes too much)

Answer (score 0):

[You might want to give this article a read](http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2014/01/19/gunicorn-heroku-django/) and investigate a request buffering HTTP server such as Waitress.